# How to get name from a list of employees

Tags: java, arrays, list

I am trying to print "name" of an employee from a list of employees. Below is my pojo class.

```
import java.time.LocalDate;

public class Employee {

    private String name;
    private String empID;
    private Designation designation;
    private LocalDate dateOfJoining;
    private int monthlySalary;

    public Employee(String name, String empID, Designation designation, LocalDate dateOfJoining, int monthlySalary) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.empID = empID;
        this.designation = designation;
        this.dateOfJoining = dateOfJoining;
        this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
    }

    public Employee() {
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(String empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public Designation getDesignation() {
        return designation;
    }

    public void setDesignation(Designation designation) {
        this.designation = designation;
    }

    public LocalDate getDOJ() {
        return dateOfJoining;
    }

    public void setDOJ(LocalDate dOJ) {
        dateOfJoining = dOJ;
    }

    public int getMonthlySalary() {
        return monthlySalary;
    }

    public void setMonthlySalary(int monthlySalary) {
        this.monthlySalary = monthlySalary;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((dateOfJoining == null) ? 0 : dateOfJoining.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((designation == null) ? 0 : designation.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((empID == null) ? 0 : empID.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + monthlySalary;
        result = prime * result + ((name == null) ? 0 : name.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Employee other = (Employee) obj;
        if (dateOfJoining == null) {
            if (other.dateOfJoining != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!dateOfJoining.equals(other.dateOfJoining))
            return false;
        if (designation == null) {
            if (other.designation != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!designation.equals(other.designation))
            return false;
        if (empID == null) {
            if (other.empID != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!empID.equals(other.empID))
            return false;
        if (monthlySalary != other.monthlySalary)
            return false;
        if (name == null) {
            if (other.name != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!name.equals(other.name))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Employee [name=" + name + ", empID=" + empID + ", designation=" + designation + ", DOJ=" + dateOfJoining
                + ", monthlySalary=" + monthlySalary + "]";
    }

}
```

Now while I am trying to print the "name", I am getting null value.
Please see as below,

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.List;

public class Employecomparable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JoiningDate jd = new JoiningDate();
        Employee emp = new Employee();
        List<Employee> listofemployee = new ArrayList<>();

        listofemployee.add(new Employee("abc", "12345", Designation.ASE,jd.date1 , 20000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("abcd", "24680", Designation.SE, jd.date2, 30000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("abcde", "13570", Designation.SSE,jd.date3, 40000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("abcdef", "13690", Designation.TL, jd.date4, 60000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("xyz", "10909", Designation.AM, jd.date5, 800000));
        listofemployee.add(new Employee("koool", "89076", Designation.M, jd.date6, 2000));
        System.out.println("The name of employee is "+emp.getName());
```

I am getting the output as "null".
In console I get, The name of employee is null.
How do i print the name?
Please help!

Comment: You are adding _six_ employees to a list.  Which one's name do you want to print?

Comment: suppose i want to print the name of the first employee?how do i do that?

Comment: You are not setting any property in emp object that you created

Answer (score 1):

To print the name of a particular employee, kindly update the emp object.

```
emp = listofemployee.get(indexWithinTheList);
System.out.println("The name of employee is "+emp.getName());
```

**Example**:

```
emp = listofemployee.get(0);
System.out.println("The name of employee is "+emp.getName());

Output : The name of employee is abc
```

Answer (score 0):

You may want to iterate over your employee and then print the name. Reason you get `null` is you created `Employee` object with default constructor. Which would mean name being string object would take default null value which is what you see.

If you want to print employee names, you could do the following:

```
for (Employee employee: listofemployee) {
    System.out.println("The name of employee is " + employee.getName());
}
```

Since you are using `List` interface, you can access individual object by it's index. E.g. to get first employee name:

```
System.out.println("The name of employee is " + listofemployee.get(0).getName());
```

Answer (score 0):

1 - Create Employee object like below:-

> Employee emp =new Employee("xyz", "10909", Designation.AM, jd.date5,
>   800000);

2 - Then store into list.

3 - After that iterate over list and print result as per your requirement.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    JoiningDate jd = new JoiningDate();
    Employee emp = new Employee();
    List<Employee> listofemployee = new ArrayList<>();
    emp = new Employee("abc", "12345", Designation.ASE,jd.date1 , 20000);
    listofemployee.add(emp);
    emp =new Employee("abcd", "24680", Designation.SE, jd.date2, 30000);
    listofemployee.add(emp);
    emp =new Employee("abcde", "13570", Designation.SSE,jd.date3, 40000);
    listofemployee.add(emp);
    emp = new Employee("abcdef", "13690", Designation.TL, jd.date4, 60000);
    listofemployee.add(emp);
    emp =new Employee("koool", "89076", Designation.M, jd.date6, 2000);
    listofemployee.add(emp);
    emp =new Employee("xyz", "10909", Designation.AM, jd.date5, 800000);
    listofemployee.add(emp);

    System.out.println("The name of employee is "+emp.getName());


    Iterator<Employee> itr = listofemployee.iterator(); 

    // checking the next element availabilty 
    while (itr.hasNext()) 
    { 
       System.out.println("name " + (itr.next()).getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: @michalk Done. thanks. It just slipped through my mind.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because you have created the Employee object like below.
`Employee emp = new Employee();` After that you are populating the list using new Employee. But you have not set any value to variable emp.so getName from emp will return null. If you want to get the value from emp. You first need to set the name using `emp.SetName("Any name");` No you will get the value using `emp.getName();`

Answer (score 0):

**1) you are trying to print name of employee which is an empty object which is emp.
2) you have to either get one of the employee object from the list by any index
say for eg:**

```
   Employee emp = listofemployee.get(0);
   and then you can System.out.println(emp.getName());
```

**Or if you want print name of all employees in this way**

```
   listofemployee.stream().forEach(e->System.out.prinltn(e.getName()));
```

**this will print names of all employees**